# Javascript prototypes trying to understand

Tags: javascript

I am only starting to learn JavaScript and encounered with a problem trying to understand how the prorotypes work.

I got the following code

```
var parent = {
    city : "Cardiff",
    hair : "white",
    surname : "Smith",
    name : "John"
};

var child = Object.create(parent);{
    name : "Mike"
};

child.name
```

And when I call `child.name` it returns me `John` and not `Mike`.
I tried to google, change the code, browsed through some reference books but still can't find the reason why am I returned `John`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var child = Object.create(parent);{
    name : "Mike"
};
```

Is just

```
var child = Object.create(parent);

{
    name : "Mike"
};
```

So you create `child` then create some other random object with one property `name` whose value is `"Mike"`.